# Empty Exposed Dropdown menu when placed inside a custom dialog layout

Tags: java, android, material-design, material-components-android

I'm trying to implement an Exposed Dropdown menu on an AlertDialog with a custom layout defined in dialog_main_createremote.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/dialog_main_textinput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Category">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_main_dropdown"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="none"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As per Material Design Guidelines, items need a layout for the dropdown menu to appear, so I created the following in the dropdown_item.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1" />
```

Finally, I started to generate the AlertDialog with a MaterialAlertDialogBuilder, then defined and instantiated a LayoutInflater which I used to get dialog's custom view and get access to the setAdapter method, but after setting the adapter and showing the dialog all I can get is an Outlined TextInputLayout without any dropdown menu.

So that's it, thanks in advance for any suggestions/solutions, also, as you may have noticed, I'm new to android development, so, if possible and of course, if you have time in your hands, elaborate your answer or point to a specific resource where I could get more info.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RemoteListViewModel remoteListViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.main_recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final RemoteAdapter adapter = new RemoteAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        remoteListViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(RemoteListViewModel.class);
        remoteListViewModel.getAllRemotes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Remote>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Remote> remotes) {
                adapter.setRemotes(remotes);
            }
        });
        
        ExtendedFloatingActionButton createButton = findViewById(R.id.create_efab);

        createButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MaterialAlertDialogBuilder builder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
                final View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_main_createremote, null);
                AutoCompleteTextView actv = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_main_dropdown);
                String categories[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories);
                actv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.dropdown_item, categories));
                builder.setView(R.layout.dialog_main_createremote);
                builder.setTitle("Set control params");
                builder.setNegativeButton("Nope", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                builder.setPositiveButton("Okey", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```